# 301 redirect on exact page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently getting 404 errors on Google crawler.

Situation:

There are user profiles under this domain structure:

www.domain.com/user/username

but: www.domain.com/user is not a real page so it throws a 404 error.

www.domain.com/users exists.

So, is there a way to redirect people who type in www.domain.com/user to www.domain.com/users without affecting www.domain.com/user/username ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `RewriteRule` with an expression that anchors the end of the URL at `user` with `$` can be rewritten accordingly. The `/?` allows for an optional trailing `/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/?$ users [L,R=301]
```

The above will redirect the browser so the URL `/users` shows in the address bar. If you only want a silent internal rewrite, change `[L,R=301]` to `[L]`.

If you don't want to invoke mod_rewrite, you can probably use a `RedirectMatch` instead.

```
RedirectMatch ^/user/?$ http://example.com/users
```